# Scroll to xib (pagecontrol)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i had a small question, i'm using this code to scroll from color to color:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
```

you can scroll from color to color, but is there a way to scroll to another xib file?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        [subview release];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial will help you out: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/ 
(i think that you've use this tutorial)

but on the last line of the tutorial:

> Update: In the comments, some people have asked about placing buttons
>   inside the scroll view, and also about setting up the scroll view
>   using Interface Builder. I’ve added some code that includes buttons
>   here, and a version using Interface Builder here.

So here is the link to move to xib files: https://github.com/cwalcott/UIScrollView-Paging/tree/buttons-ib

Good luck,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preparing UIView's and adding them to a scrollview, you could indeed use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed...` to load several nib (which are compiled xib) and add them to a scrollview, and then scroll them up and down, or back and forth.